# Реализация всплывающей подсказки

Tags: java, android

Имеется поле для ввода и кнопка, если мы не заполним данное поле и нажмем на кнопку, выводится вот такая ошибка в виде подсказки, как на скриншоте ниже.
Подсказка накладывается поверх всех остальных элементов, интересует каким образом можно реализовать это, спасибо)

[image: не может быть пустым]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это стандартный функционал виджета `EditText` и реализуется методом [`setError("Message")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)). Так же возможен перегруженный метод с собственной иконкой:

```
editText.setError("message", R.drawable.icon_error);
```

Проверка на пусстое поле может быть такой:

```
final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()  {

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)  {
     if (s.length() <= 0) {
        firstName.setError("Не может быть пустым");
     } else {
        firstName.setError(null);
     }
   }
});
```

**UPDATE**: Так же вы можете использовать более стильный виджет из библиотеки поддержки `TextInputLayout` и [выводить ошибки](http://www.materialdoc.com/user-input-errors/) такого вида:

[image: scr]

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout  
    android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/First_name" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

---

```
TextInputLayout inputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);  
inputLayout.setError("First name is required"); // show error  
inputLayout.setError(null); // hide error
```

Comment: да, действительно стандартный) большое спасибо)